# Passwordless connectionstring for .net core 5 worker service

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, backgroundworker

I am creating .Net Core 5 windows service (using worker process template) which has azure SQL DB implementation.

I have a requirement to create a SQL connection string without userid and password.

I know there is something called `Managed Identities` however so far I read it only talks about
achieving this for azure APP services. Could not find any example with .Net Core worker service

As I am creating windows service and it will be deployed in multiple VMs how to create connection string without userid and password?

Comment: `DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$` if they run as Network Service.

Answer (score 0):

On workaround try with these

**1)** **Azure AD token, Use the Azure Active directory for Azure SQL Server Authentication**

This authentication method allows middle-tier services to obtain JSON Web Tokens (JWT) to connect to the database in SQL Database, the SQL Managed Instance, or Azure Synapse by obtaining a token from Azure AD. This method enables various application scenarios including service identities, service principals, and applications using certificate-based authentication. You must complete four basic steps to use Azure AD token authentication:

- Register your application with Azure Active Directory and get the
  client ID for your code.
- Create a database user representing the application.
- Create a certificate on the client computer runs the application.
- Add the certificate as a key for your application.

Example:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=testdb;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.AccessToken = "Your JWT token";
conn.Open();
```

For more details refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell

**2)**
**Try with the storing the connection string(sensitive information ) in Azure Key Vault and retrieving it dynamically for establishing database connection.**

For more details refer this document :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you follow these steps.

#### Set up managed identity on your VMs

- Create a managed identity on each of the VMs.
- Grant these managed identities access to the Azure SQL database by creating a contained database user, and assigning the right permissions to these users.

See this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql), up to and including the "Create contained user" section.

#### Leverage managed identity from your application

The recent versions of the .NET SQL driver, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, can handle the process of acquiring a token from Azure Active Directory and using it during the SQL queries. This replaces the common authentication method of using a username and password in the connection string.

This means that as a consumer, you don't need to deal with the token acquisition process, nor the caching or the renewal of the tokens.

A couple of resources to do this:

- Official Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15.
- A blog post I wrote showing how to leverage the newer versions of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient: https://mderriey.com/2021/07/23/new-easy-way-to-use-aad-auth-with-azure-sql/.